# Write to database and return at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a situation where I wish to return data or redirect the user elsewhere, and also log information to a database at the same time.

My current code is similar to the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendUser(string target)
{
    Target dbTarget = await DbContext.Targets.SingleOrDefaultAsync(target => target.url == target);
    dbTarget.LastAccess = DateTime.Now();
    dbTarget.TimesAccessed = dbTarget.TimesAccessed++;
    DbContext.Targets.Update(dbTarget);
    DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    Redirect(target);
}
```

I would like this to Redirect the user, but log to the database seperately, without the users request having for the database update to complete.

One solution is to create a seperate method in the controller and just POST the new log item to it, which would cause a seperate request, however I wonder if there is a better method that does not require adding extra authentication steps and methods?

Comment: What you'd do is run the database logging in a different thread, i.e. `Task.Run`. Unfortunately, however, the `DbContext` is (I assume) scoped to the request and may have some issues when usage is attempted after the request is completed. What I'd suggest is to use an [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) and queue and store the logs through a background task queuing mechanism.

Comment: Also note: Separating the logs storage operation from the request lifecycle may cause inconsistencies, i.e. a request to be completed without having the logs stored (e.g. during shutdown unless handled properly, due to critical error etc.). This is just for you to consider. Obviously, this is the same category of consistency issue you would get with two separate requests as you suggest.

Comment: Try instead of  DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();   
 await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); or just DbContext.SaveChanges(); Redirect will wait till all changes are saved.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); or just DbContext.SaveChanges(); Redirect will wait till all changes are saved.